# Material table with custom filter not working with user query search

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi So I'm working with matTable and I have a custom filter to filter based on multiple columns ,but i have textbox which I want to use to search the table ,based on user typed query ,but the textbox search doesn't seem to work ,I'm a beginner so ,any help will be much appreciated

```
**This particular filter is not working**

 applyFilter(event:Event) {
    const filtervalue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
    this.dataSource.filter = filtervalue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

**appcomponent.html**

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field
    *ngFor="let filter of filterSelectObj"
    style="margin-left: 15px;"
  >
    <mat-label>Filter {{ filter.name }}</mat-label>
    <select
      matNativeControl
      name="{{ filter.columnProp }}"
      [(ngModel)]="filter.modelValue"
      (change)="filterChange(filter, $event)"
    >
      <option value="">-- Select {{ filter.name }} --</option>
      <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of filter.options">
        {{ item }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>
  &nbsp;
  <button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="resetFilters()">Reset</button>
</div>
<input
  type="text"
  id="fname"
  name="fname"
  (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"
  placeholder="search"
/>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>id</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>username</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.username }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>email</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.email }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>phone</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.phone }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="website">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>website</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.website }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.status }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

**appcomponent.ts**

```
filterValues = {};
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'username',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'website',
    'status',
  ];

  filterSelectObj = [];
  constructor() {
    // Object to create Filter for
    this.filterSelectObj = [
      {
        name: 'ID',
        columnProp: 'id',
        options: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'NAME',
        columnProp: 'name',
        options: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'USERNAME',
        columnProp: 'username',
        options: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'EMAIL',
        columnProp: 'email',
        options: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'STATUS',
        columnProp: 'status',
        options: [],
      },
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRemoteData();

    // Overrride default filter behaviour of Material Datatable
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
  }

  // Get Uniqu values from columns to build filter
  getFilterObject(fullObj, key) {
    const uniqChk = [];
    fullObj.filter((obj) => {
      if (!uniqChk.includes(obj[key])) {
        uniqChk.push(obj[key]);
      }
      return obj;
    });
    return uniqChk;
  }

  // Get remote serve data using HTTP call
  getRemoteData() {
    const remoteDummyData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Leanne Graham',
        username: 'Bret',
        email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
        phone: '1-770-736-8031 x56442',
        website: 'hildegard.org',
        status: 'Active',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Ervin Howell',
        username: 'Antonette',
        email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
        phone: '010-692-6593 x09125',
        website: 'anastasia.net',
        status: 'Blocked',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Clementine Bauch',
        username: 'Samantha',
        email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net',
        phone: '1-463-123-4447',
        website: 'ramiro.info',
        status: 'Blocked',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
        username: 'Karianne',
        email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
        phone: '493-170-9623 x156',
        website: 'kale.biz',
        status: 'Active',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
        username: 'Kamren',
        email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca',
        phone: '(254)954-1289',
        website: 'demarco.info',
        status: 'Active',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Mrs. Dennis Schulist',
        username: 'Leopoldo_Corkery',
        email: 'Karley_Dach@jasper.info',
        phone: '1-477-935-8478 x6430',
        website: 'ola.org',
        status: 'In-Active',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Kurtis Weissnat',
        username: 'Elwyn.Skiles',
        email: 'Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz',
        phone: '210.067.6132',
        website: 'elvis.io',
        status: 'Active',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V',
        username: 'Maxime_Nienow',
        email: 'Sherwood@rosamond.me',
        phone: '586.493.6943 x140',
        website: 'jacynthe.com',
        status: 'In-Active',
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        name: 'Glenna Reichert',
        username: 'Delphine',
        email: 'Chaim_McDermott@dana.io',
        phone: '(775)976-6794 x41206',
        website: 'conrad.com',
        status: 'In-Active',
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Clementina DuBuque',
        username: 'Moriah.Stanton',
        email: 'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz',
        phone: '024-648-3804',
        website: 'ambrose.net',
        status: 'Active',
      },
    ];
    this.dataSource.data = remoteDummyData;

    this.filterSelectObj.filter((o) => {
      o.options = this.getFilterObject(remoteDummyData, o.columnProp);
    });
  }

  // Called on Filter change
  filterChange(filter, event) {
    //let filterValues = {}
    this.filterValues[filter.columnProp] = event.target.value
      .trim()
      .toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
  }

  // Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
  createFilter() {
    let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
      let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
      let isFilterSet = false;
      for (const col in searchTerms) {
        if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
          isFilterSet = true;
        } else {
          delete searchTerms[col];
        }
      }

      console.log(searchTerms);

      let nameSearch = () => {
        let found = false;
        if (isFilterSet) {
          for (const col in searchTerms) {
            searchTerms[col]
              .trim()
              .toLowerCase()
              .split(' ')
              .forEach((word) => {
                if (
                  data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 &&
                  isFilterSet
                ) {
                  found = true;
                }
              });
          }
          return found;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      };
      return nameSearch();
    };
    return filterFunction;
  }

  // Reset table filters
  resetFilters() {
    this.filterValues = {};
    this.filterSelectObj.forEach((value, key) => {
      value.modelValue = undefined;
    });
    this.dataSource.filter = '';
  }

  applyFilter(event:Event) {
    const filtervalue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
    this.dataSource.filter = filtervalue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

**Find the stackblitz below**

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mxhbzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,tsconfig.json,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Hello, the link to stackBlitz is useful, but the relevant part of the code should be added to the question itself, as links tend to rot with time (you can use the "edit" link below the question)

Comment: I have not enough time to do more than a quick look, but when I type into the filter text input, this error shows in console `Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`, maybe solving the error will make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you probably do not need to add so much code, try the below code

```js
createFilter() {
  return (data: any, filter: string): boolean => {
    return Object.values(data).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? true: false
  }
}
```